# Python: For loop over list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

Is there a shorter way to write

```
for x in [x for x in X if a(x)]:
    <Do something complicated with x>
```

Unfortunately, the following does not work:

```
for x in X if a(x):
    <Do something complicated with x>
```

Of course, I could achieve the desired result by

```
for x in X:
    if a(x):
        <Do something complicated with x>
```

but this would introduce an extra level of indentation

Comment: It seems to me that the penalty of extra indentation in your last possibility is more than made up for by the increased clarity. [Readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: I think my second, non-working, example would be very readable. The last possibility is not bad, but I was just curious if something like the second was possible

Answer (score 5):

1. `[b(x) for x in X if a(x)]` is the simplest but will create an unnecessary list.
2. `map(b, (x for x in X if a(x)))` will use a generator so no unneeded list will be created.

Comment: Although by the time 2 has been written, it would have made more sense as 3 lines.

Comment: `(b(x) for x in X if a(x))` will create a generator as well.

Comment: What's the point of `map(b, (x for x in X if a(x)))` if you're not going to actually run the generator? `map(...)` by itself is essentially a no-op. You need to either do `list(map(...))` or `for x in map(...):pass`. (Unless we're talking about python 2, but in that case it's not true that "no unneeded list will be created")

Comment: b(x) is actually code of block ... will update my question

Comment: @Bananach You can wrap it in a function so it is actually `b(x)`.

Comment: Yeah but the whole point of this question is to write pretty code,  not workarounds

Comment: @Bananach functions are not "workarounds". You *are* "supposed" to use short functions, not messy 100-lines-blocks-of-code.

Comment: it is not a 100 line block of code. it is a 7 line block of code, that is used only at this occasion.

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone is a fan of the following, but I quite like the map and filter funcs for readability...

```
list(map(b, filter(a, X))
```

It will achieve what you want, and I think it's easier to see what's going on.

Comment: @Elmex80s Yup, not the most efficient. Just depends on the use case. Sometimes it's worth sacrificing runtime for readability.

Comment: True, but with list comprehension you map and filter within one go.

Comment: @Elmex80s Yeah, personally, I don't have any issue with list comps, they're great; but for those not used to the language, it's another option. Of course, you could argue they should just make the leap and learn the list comp.

Comment: b(x) is actually a code of block ... will update my question